# Looking to install reduced size azure-cli on iot embedded linux device (so it takes less space on disk)

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-cli

We are trying to install azure-cli on an embedded linux device and after installation, the size of the azure-cli directory was 580MB and when the azure-iot extension was added , it is now at 613MB.

We are looking at reducing the amount of space that azure-iot is occupying since we have the native software that needs to be installed on device in addition to leaving space for o/s and other data and files. The application only takes 4M and azure-cli is taking a large chunk of space to stage the software.

Is it possible to install only core components needed to invoke a python sdk script that will be invoking libraries such as "from azure.iot.device import IoTHubDeviceClient, Message" ?

The current install was done with the following curl command below:
"curl  https://azurecliprod.blob.core.windows.net/install | bash"

Comment: What exactly do you want to use it for? There is nothing in the Azure CLI that could not achieved directly in code. That way you only get the parts you need.

Answer (score 0):

Azure CLI has [edge builds](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli#edge-builds), however this is in it's dev branch and may not yet fully released. This is a good place to start. The *deeper* solution would be to fork the repository, shave off the features that you aren't going to use to make it as light as possible and then build that version. However, this may be extra work if the 'edge builds' is sufficiently light.

Comment: Thanks but if the edge build is not in production, I would be comfortable in installing this version in production.

Comment: I'll update my comment if it ever goes into the `main` build.

Comment: I'm fairly certain they're using "edge builds" in the meaning of "HEAD builds", completely not related to "running on IoT Edge".  This is why it's a bad idea to use common names for products...